# Php как отправить CORS запрос?

Tags: php

PHP может отправлять запросы на подобие этого:

```
    <?php
$url = 'http://hey.net';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Origin: applicsation/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nOrigin: applicsation/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Но как отправить CORS запрос? Чтобы я мог прочитать ответ.

Надо чтобы в запросе присутствовали куки от сайта

Comment: Надо чтобы в запросе присутствовали куки от сайта

Comment: используйте [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive можете привести пример отправки CORS запроса через curl с куками от сайта